# Android How to get current location in tunnel

Tags: android, location, google-api-client

I am getting current location using FusedLocationApi. its working fine but sometimes its not working in tunnel. getting wrong location latitude and longitude in tunnel. I calculate distance between current location and last location and distance getting more then 100 km in tunnel. means in tunnel FusedLocationApi completely not working.

```
    private static final long INTERVAL = 5 * 1000;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 5 * 1000;
    private static final int SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT = 5;
    public LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    public GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

  @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //location service
        createLocationRequest();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this).build();


    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    public void startLocationUpdates() {
        PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d("TAG", "Location update started ..............: ");

    }
```

Comment: Logical, isn't it? In tunnel is no signal. Do it like most of the GPS navigations. When you enter tunnel, you know the speed and use that speed to calculate where you should be at specific time.

Comment: You'd need to know the direction you're travelling though. So good luck if you change direction while in the tunnel!

Comment: when GPS is unavailable, the location is calculated based on the other not accurate methods, that's why it is so different. So it's up to you to think about a way to do that in tunnel.